# Using “They” Vs. “You” After using unless

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct ? Should it be:

> Unless you keep your teeth clean, **they** won’t stay healthy.

or:

> Unless you keep your teeth clean, **You** won’t stay healthy.

The question is from a practice test:

> To stay healthy, You have to keep your teeth clean. Use **Unless**

My english teacher says (first sentence) is the right one.

But i say **both of them** , because Your teeth are a part of your Body,So we can say You if we talk about it in general.

Comment: Both are possible, however, your teacher may have been instructed to only accept one "correct" answer, probably in a list supplied with the test, and may not have the courage (or knowledge) to tell you that you are right.

Comment: I agree with Michael. However, considering the focus lies on cleaning one's teeth, it's understandable that reference should be made to the teeth alone in the result. Being healthy involves much more that just keeping your teeth clean.

Comment: @Alandosman I have made my comment an answer so that you can close out the question.

Comment: Tell your teacher, the question is not about grammar. Gees.

Comment: @Lambie i told him , but he didn’t listen 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge sentence doesn't talk about healthy teeth. It talks about someone or something that is "to stay healthy," and the nearest person or thing to the phrase is you. I would read it to mean "If you want to stay healthy, you must keep your teeth clean." That makes "unless... ,you have to keep your teeth clean the correct answer.